# do app signing certificate and upload certificate change on each release

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I recently uploaded my app to play store but I was unable to generate OTP it showed firebase exception that my app was unauthorized and asked me to verify package name and SHA-1 keys.

I found out that I had to enter new keys from play console to my app settings so I uploaded both App signing certificate and upload certificate.

I have some doubts in mind

1) does App signing certificate or upload certificate change on every release? however, I will be generating signed APK with the same file for each release.

2) which key should I use on my firebase, app signing key or the upload key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. does App signing certificate or upload certificate change on every release? however, I will be generating signed APK with the same file for each release.

No, the app sign certificate doesn't ever change. If you handle it yourself and lose it, it's lost. You will be unable to update the app anymore. Can't be changed even if you want to if set up that way.

Upload key is just to verify that you are uploading the same app. It's just between you and google play. If lost you can *request* to get a new one. But doesn't change otherwise.

> 2. which key should I use on my firebase, app signing key or the upload key?

The app signing key. So if you are using the upload key, meaning you let Google sign it, you can then check in the developer console what the real SHA-1 is.